# Best practice how to unwrap CancellationToken when using linked CancellationTokenSource

Tags: .net, vb.net, cancellation

I'm currently adopting [.NET Cancellation Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/05/22/9635790.aspx) in my app. It appears that I need to use linked `CancellationTokenSource` every now and then and I have found out tedious to "unwrap" `OperationCanceledException` in every matching catch so that it contains correct `CancellationToken`. I would like to ask:

1. Is there any out-of-the box solution to facilitate this case?
2. What is "best practice" which deals with it?

My question regards .NET 4. I'm also attaching code sample which shows what I'm talking about:

```
Using linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(externalCancelToken, internalCancelToken)
    Try
        myRequest.Dispatch(linkedCts.Token)

    Catch ex As WebException When ex.Status = WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled
        If externalCancelToken.IsCancellationRequested Then
            Throw New OperationCanceledException(externalCancelToken)
        ElseIf internalCancelToken.IsCancellationRequested Then
            Throw New OperationCanceledException(internalCancelToken)
        Else
            Throw
        End If

    Catch ex As OperationCanceledException
        If ex.CancellationToken = linkedCts.Token Then
            If externalCancelToken.IsCancellationRequested Then
                Throw New OperationCanceledException(Nothing, ex, externalCancelToken)
            ElseIf internalCancelToken.IsCancellationRequested Then
                Throw New OperationCanceledException(Nothing, ex, internalCancelToken)
            End If
        End If

    End Try
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to google some ideas but found nothing. So I came up with following wrapper for linked `CancellationTokenSource`-es:

```
Imports System.Threading


Namespace Threading

    Public Class LinkedCancellationTokenSource
        Implements IDisposable


        Public ReadOnly Property Token As CancellationToken
            Get
                Return Me.internalSource.Token
            End Get
        End Property


        Public ReadOnly Property IsCancellationRequested As Boolean
            Get
                Return Me.internalSource.IsCancellationRequested
            End Get
        End Property


        Private ReadOnly tokens As CancellationToken()
        Private ReadOnly internalSource As CancellationTokenSource


        Private Sub New(internalSource As CancellationTokenSource, tokens As CancellationToken())
            Me.internalSource = internalSource
            Me.tokens = tokens
        End Sub


        Public Sub Cancel()
            Me.internalSource.Cancel()
        End Sub


        ''' 
        ''' Tries to unwrap  to any contained 
        '''  in this source. If token in exception is unknown,
        ''' nothing will be thrown and you have to elevate.
        ''' 
        ''' Caught exception which should be unwrapped.
        ''' Message which will be appended to the unwrapped exception.
        Public Sub ThrowIfCausedCancelOf(ex As OperationCanceledException, Optional message As String = Nothing)
            If ex.CancellationToken = Me.Token Then
                Me.ThrowIfAnyCancellationRequested(ex, message)
            End If
        End Sub


        ''' 
        ''' Throws  if any of contained tokens has had 
        ''' cancellation requested.
        ''' 
        Public Sub ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
            Me.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(Nothing, Nothing)
        End Sub


        ''' 
        ''' Throws  if any of contained tokens has had 
        ''' cancellation requested.
        ''' 
        Public Sub ThrowIfCancellationRequested(message As String)
            Me.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(Nothing, message)
        End Sub


        ''' 
        ''' Throws  if any of contained tokens has had 
        ''' cancellation requested.
        ''' 
        Public Sub ThrowIfCancellationRequested(ex As Exception, Optional message As String = Nothing)
            For i = 0 To Me.tokens.Length - 1
                If Me.tokens(i).IsCancellationRequested Then
                    Throw New OperationCanceledException(message, ex, Me.tokens(i))
                End If
            Next
        End Sub


        Public Shared Function Create(token1 As CancellationToken, token2 As CancellationToken) As LinkedCancellationTokenSource
            Dim internalSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(token1, token2)
            Return New LinkedCancellationTokenSource(internalSource, {token1, token2})
        End Function


        Public Shared Function Create(ParamArray tokens As CancellationToken()) As LinkedCancellationTokenSource
            Dim internalSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(tokens)
            Return New LinkedCancellationTokenSource(internalSource, tokens)
        End Function

#Region "IDisposable Support"
        Private disposedValue As Boolean ' To detect redundant calls

        ' IDisposable
        Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
            If Not Me.disposedValue Then
                If disposing Then
                    ' dispose managed state (managed objects).
                    Me.internalSource.Dispose()
                End If

                ' free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override Finalize() below.
                ' set large fields to null.
            End If
            Me.disposedValue = True
        End Sub

        ' override Finalize() only if Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
        'Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
        '    ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean) above.
        '    Dispose(False)
        '    MyBase.Finalize()
        'End Sub

        ' This code added by Visual Basic to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
        Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
            ' Do not change this code.  Put cleanup code in Dispose(disposing As Boolean) above.
            Dispose(True)
            GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
        End Sub

#End Region

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Usage in mentioned example:

```
Using linkedCts = LinkedCancellationTokenSource.Create(externalCancelToken, internalCancelToken)
    Try
        myRequest.Dispatch(linkedCts.Token)

    Catch ex As WebException When ex.Status = WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled
        linkedCts.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(ex)
        Throw

    Catch ex As OperationCanceledException
        linkedCts.ThrowIfCausedCancelOf(ex)
        Throw

    End Try
End Using
```

Please vote up/down whether this is good or bad solution. Also ideas for better naming of methods are welcome.